# GNU date and custom formats

Tags: linux, bash, date, gnu

I have some strings in a specific date format that I'd like to work on using the GNU date command (coreutils 8.20). I can get date to output using the +FORMAT string, but not to understand strings input into it using the same string. I'm quite sure I'm missing something obvious. What gives?

```
teggl@mckinley { ~/scripts }$ date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S
20131202T182052
teggl@mckinley { ~/scripts }$ date --date="20131202T182052" +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S
date: invalid date ‘20131202T182052’
```

Note: I'm not looking for awk-y string parsing, I need date to understand the date input into it, so it knows if it's valid (e.g. the date 20140231T120000 would be impossible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

per the man page:

> The  --date=STRING  is  a  mostly  free  format  human  readable date
>   string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29
>   16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items
>   indicating calendar date,  time  of  day, time  zone,  day of week,
>   relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates
>   the beginning of the day. The date string format is more complex than
>   is easily documented here but is fully described in the info
>   documentation.

The "T" seems to confuse it. This works:

```
$ date --date="2013-12-02 18:20:52" +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S
20131202T182052
```

The output format has nothing to do with the input format.

Comment: sorry, my original example (with a "T") was wrong and was showing 3:20am instead of 6:20pm for some reason.

Comment: Thanks; it was specifically the trouble that date was having with my input format that was confusing me though, as from what I can tell it should work fine as long as you give it the input +FORMAT string. I know it works with other, easier to parse formats

Comment: the +FORMAT string *only* affects the output.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had missed this line in the man page: "FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted sequences are...<snip>". RTFM would have won the day as usual!

Answer (score 1):

If that is the input format you are stuck with, you may need to reformat it before sending it to date:

```
datestr=20131202T182052
datestr=$( echo $datestr | sed -e 's/T/ /' -e 's/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1-\2-/' -e 's/ \([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/ \1:\2:/' )

date --date="$datestr" +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S
```

Comment: I was hoping to stay away from reformatting the string in-flight, but this might be as good as it's going to get!