# Linux Shell Script - Date format not working

Tags: linux, shell

I am getting date in following format from a system and I need to use it for calculating some time difference.

Input format - 30-MAR-18 01.40.04.812030 AM PST

I am using following code but I am getting format errors.

```
#!/usr/bin
start_string="30-MAR-18 01.40.04.812030 AM PST"
TZ=GMT date --date="$start_string" "+%s" 
#Above line is just to convert into seconds and print
```

This throws the error "date: invalid date ‘30-MAR-18 01.40.04.812030 AM PST’"

I am lost on how to convert this into date format and then use it.

All help appreciated.

This is different from question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342620/gnu-date-and-custom-formats) because I am dealing with an input that has a "." and not a ":" as the time separator.

Comment: seems you dont have the GNU date. type date --version and check the output

Comment: Here is version output. date (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin` is not a valid shebang. Maybe you want `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` there, depending on whether your script attempts to use any Bash syntax. (The fragment you posted doesn't.)

Comment: Sorry about shebang. Updated to /bin/bash - same result.

Comment: If you have dot, you need to replace it with `:`. Having `a` in place of `b` does not make it a unique question. Look at the second answer of the duplicate question, it explains how to format the string as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the format like this:

```
start_string="30-MAR-18 01:40:04.812030 AM PST"
```

Comment: The issue is that is how input comes and I am not allowed to modify it. Your solution will work if I can modify the input.